# Ascertain the position within a list of elements of the parent of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of elements similar to simplified HTML below. When one of the images is clicked some JavaScript if fired, and the image that is clicked becomes `this.theImage`.

I now need to get the position of the image; for example if the first image was clicked, the position should be 1, if the second is clicked it should be 2, and so on.

I could use `var elements = $('.image-preview', '#gallery');`, to take a list of all elements with the `image-preview` class, and then loop through them and match the ID to the image, but that seems really inefficient.

Is there another way of achieving this task that is more efficient?

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="image-preview">
        <img id="image-1" src="http://www.mysite.com/image1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview">
        <img id="image-2" src="http://www.mysite.com/image2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview">
        <img id="image-3" src="http://www.mysite.com/image3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview">
        <img id="image-4" src="http://www.mysite.com/image4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get it, you catch a click on the image like this

```
$('.image-preview img').on('click', function() {

});
```

and then to get the index you'd do

```
$('.image-preview img').on('click', function() {
    var index = $('.image-preview img').index(this);
});
```

note that it's zero based

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ6h6/1/)

Comment: I'll edit my question to make it more clear, but what I in fact have is `$('.image-preview img'.).on('click', functino(){...`. Therefore, it's the element under `image-preview` that I have selected. However, looking at your example, I'm wondering if I could use `.index(this.find('image-preview')`...

Comment: You're quite right, I done some testing and that works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Array.prototype.indexOf` do it for you:

```
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery'),
    els = [].slice.call(gallery.getElementsByTagName('img'));
gallery.onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'img') return;
    var position = els.indexOf(e.target);
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ6h6/2/)